# Distributed Computing: Cache user based messages for x minutes and then persist

Tags: redis, cassandra, hbase, distributed-computing

1. I have a usecase in which I receive notifications for users from other users.
2. Most of the time these notifications are consumed by other users within X minutes.
3. Once consumed I need not save the notification data on my backend. Ordered delivery of notification is important to users

I want to think of a caching based solution or a store which can keep the notifications in memory for x minutes and then persist it at the same time gives ordered notifications user wise.

Comment: Okay I'm a little confused: You need "not save the notification data on my backend" then in the end you ask "and then persist it"

Which is it ?

Comment: persist till it gets delivered to the user. Need not save it forever is what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Use [Distributed Messaging](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/run-time-data-sharing.html) to enable realtime messaging. You should use the **Application Initiated Custom Events** feature.

Btw, TayzGrid is an Open source In-Memory Data Grid also known as Distributed Cache in your case.

Comment: I cannot push the notification as in when it comes. It has to be pulled from somewhere when User comes online.

Comment: So its basically a producer consumer model. Producer A will keep on producing notifications irrespective if there is any listener and once a consumer comes online it will fetch all the notifications and then the data will become irrelevant ?

Comment: Yes  , if the user is online , it will be directly written to its socket else has to be saved somewhere and then later polled by user when it comes online